# Close connection when create connection mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm used a multiple databases for every request , I createConnection to choose database and read/write data. But when everything is done how can I close this connection ?

```
//create connection every request

`const connection = mongoose.createConnection('uri');`
```

Answer (score 0):

For closing connection. Just use:

```
mongoose.connection.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this :

```
const conn = mongoose.connect('uri');

conn.disconnect();
```

Comment: `TypeError: db.disconnect is not a function`